# ¿ Cómo se actualiza o configura la base de datos MySQL en Spring Roo dentro del IDE Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)?

Tags: mysql, spring, gvnix

Después de crear el proyecto desde el `Roll Shell` del `IDE Eclipse` ,escribo lo siguiente :

`jpa setup --database MYSQL --provider HIBERNATE`

Me aparecen las siguientes indicaciones

`Created SPRING_CONFIG_ROOT\database.properties
Please update your database details in src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/database.properties.`

Dentro del archivo y me aparece estas lineas de código.

```
#Updated at Mon May 16 03:17:02 CEST 2016
#Mon May 16 03:17:02 CEST 2016
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306
database.username=usuario
database.password=contra
```

He buscado información para solventar el problema , pero la información que he encontrado es para resolverlo con `POSTGRES` y por mucho que lo intento no consiguo solucionarlo.

Comment: Buenas: No entiendo cuál es el problema. En ese mensaje sólo te está indicando que cambies la configuración por defecto de la BDD desde ese fichero. No es un problema en sí, sólo un consejo...

Comment: Lo que indica ese mensaje es que en tu archivo `database.properties` debes colocar los valores reales de la conexión sobre la que vas a trabajar, no hay problema alguno aquí.

Answer (score 1):

Por ejemplo, si tu base de datos tienes como credenciales y datos de conexión lo siguiente:

1. User: myuser
2. Password: mypassword
3. Database name o sid: mydatabase

Tu archivo de configuración debe quedar así:

```
#Updated at Mon May 16 03:17:02 CEST 2016
#Mon May 16 03:17:02 CEST 2016
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/mydatabase
database.username=myuser
database.password=mypassword
```

En caso de que no sea en tu propia máquina en donde corre el servicio de MySQL, en lugar de `localhost` debes colocar el IP del equipo en donde se ejecute el servicio de MySQL. De igual manera, pasaría con el número de puerto, si es que llega a ser diferente.

Comment: 1 milllón de gracias , tu explicación es clara y concisa , me ha ayudado mucho , era más sencillo de lo que me creía.